# mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request function

Tags: apache, fastcgi

I keep on getting warning in my error logs:

```
(103)Software caused connection abort: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request function
```

Here is my fcgid.conf

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
SocketPath /var/lib/httpd/fcgid/sock
IdleTimeout 200
IdleScanInterval 200
ProcessLifeTime 1000
MaxProcessCount 1000
DefaultMinClassProcessCount 3
DefaultMaxClassProcessCount 100
IPCConnectTimeout 8
IPCCommTimeout 200
BusyTimeout 300
</IfModule>
```

The server serves up a 500 error once in a while, then is pretty speedy for a while, then serves up another 500 error... Is there anyway to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default FastCGI processes exit after 500 requests. You can either raise PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS (in the wrapper) or limit FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess to 500.

See http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#examples "Special PHP considerations"

Comment: so `FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 500` would go into my fcgid.conf correct?

Comment: I'm not sure how your setup looks. To be safe insert it into the <IfModule mod_fcgid.c> block.

Comment: I must have a different setup I get `Invalid command 'MaxRequestsPerProcess'`

Comment: assuming mod_fcgid is loaded unconditionally in the httpd.conf: Can you add `FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess` to your httpd.conf without any <IfModule> directive?

Comment: Also, which version of mod_fcgid are you using?